# Language icon is missing from the Cinnamon settings! (Debian 11 installed with Cinnamon)

Tags: cinnamon, locale

Working in a multicultural environment, I recently needed to switch the language displayed in my computer GUI (Debian 11 installed with Cinnamon). And I did not manage to do it easily!

I have been searching around for a while to find out how to add an additional language to my new Cinnamon installation. Obviously, reading from the internet, there should be a **Languages icon** in Cinnamon **System Settings** panel.

But this icon does not exist on my installation. Where did it go?

**How can I have it back?**

The workaround I used:

- Close the Cinnamon session and open a Gnome session
- Go to the Gnome system settings, choose the Country and Language menu, and select the
  language.
- Then go back to a Cinnamon session

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon, has a standard plugin `keyboard`. You should add it on the panel.

In the System Settings, in section 'Hardware' look for the 'Keyboard'. It has a tab 'Layouts'.

There you can find a setting 'Use country flag to represent keyboard layout'. Unchecked - you would have two letters which represent language, checked - flag. The image comes from the `keyboard` plugin, so do not forget to add it.

On the same 'Layouts' page you will find layouts themselves. And a button 'Options' which will open a xkdb settings window.